# Insert a word document into another word document without losing formatting

Tags: ms-word, office365

I am working on my portfolio for grad school and I am having an issue with inserting a word document into another and keeping the original formatting of both. I built the main document so that all I would need to do is insert my supporting documentation which has to be of a different format. I tried next page section breaks and it generates the next page but all the formatting is still tied to the main document.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a regular copy and paste. Control+C on source and Control+V on destiny. Best.

Comment: I tied that but the background color and the border from the main document proceed onto the supporting documentation.

Comment: Maybe a 100% percent automated solution is not possible, probably you would have to do a little job adapting parts. If the production is made to be printed, then I think things get better, cause you can print separated documents and then join'em. Almost the same would be done if the product destination is a PDF. There are softs that easily split and merge pdf files.

Comment: The final document has to be both printed and given to the instructor in a docx file.